# Há uma alternativa culta para o anglicismo / neologismo "gamificar"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, estrangeirismos, neologismos

Muitas corporações agora estão usando este jargão, "gamificar"; que inclusive já se aninhou em dicionários mais arrojados, como o [dicionárioinformal:](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/gamifica%E7%E3o/)

> É o uso de mecânicas e dinâmicas de jogos para engajar pessoas, resolver problemas e melhorar o aprendizado, motivando ações e comportamentos em ambientes fora do contexto de jogos.

ou a [Infopédia:](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

> uso de técnicas características de videojogos em situações do mundo real, aplicadas em variados campos de atividade, tais como a educação, saúde, política e desporto, com o objetivo de resolver problemas práticos ou consciencializar ou motivar um público específico para um determinado assunto; ludificação.

Mas o termo soa extremamente áspero. Existe alternativa dentro do léxico português?

Comment: Talvez "ludificar"? http://www.opusphere.com/ludificacao-ou-gamificacao/

Comment: @hugo por favor evites responder nos comentários. O comentário é muito volátil e não pode ser votado pela comunidade. Coloque uma resposta com a tua sugestão.

Comment: No caso, optei pelo comentário porque as informações que encontrei (pelo menos na minha opinião) não são suficicentes para uma resposta satisfatória: ela ficaria muito parecida com o comentário, com praticamente nada a acrescentar - somente uma frase e um link - o que pra mim é uma resposta bem "pobre" (sei que há muitas respostas assim, mas eu prefiro não fazê-lo). Se eu encontrar mais informações, escrevo uma resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Tal como Hugo disse no comentário, "ludificar" é a alternativa nativa para "gamificar".

### Da definição do termo

O termo "ludificar" como sinônimo de "gamificar" consta no dicionário Priberam, nas seguintes entradas: [*ludificar*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ludificar) e [*ludificação*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

O termo "ludificação" consta na Wikipedia [no artigo sobre esse assunto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Até o final de 2012, o artigo chamava-se "gamificação"  mas uma edição alterou-o para "ludificação", o que gerou esta [discussão quanto ao nome](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discuss%C3%A3o:Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Hoje o artigo segue o mesmo padrão da Wikipedia [hispanófona](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludificaci%C3%B3n), [catalã](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludificaci%C3%B3) e [francófona](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludification) (que alteraram o nome do artigo para "ludificación/ludification", ver cognatos abaixo).

Há também esta outra discussão [no opusphere.com](http://www.opusphere.com/ludificacao-ou-gamificacao/) quanto ao uso de "ludificar" vs. "gamificar".

### Do uso do termo

Em Julho de 2017, o Google indexava [50.9 mil resultados](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=pt&q=%22ludificar%22+OR+%22ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22) para "ludificar" ou "ludificação", todos referentes ao sentido de gamificar. Essa quantidade (mesmo sendo inferior aos [342 mil resultados](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=pt&q=%22gamificar%22+OR+%22gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22) para "gamificar" ou "gamificação") ainda é grande o suficiente para sabermos que este termo está vivo na língua. Este resultado pode ser influenciado pelas páginas em outras línguas que também possuem "ludificar" e "gamificar".

Há vários artigos que usam o termo "ludificar" como alternativa culta para o anglicismo "gamificar", tais como um sobre [a teoria da ludificação](http://www.proceedings.blucher.com.br/article-details/a-teoria-da-ludificao-e-os-ambientes-responsivos-24894), outro sobre [o uso técnicas lúdicas para o tratamento de diabetes](https://repositorio.ufsc.br/handle/123456789/174022) e outro sobre a [ludificação didática](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/333072692X).

### Dos cognatos

Em espanhol, usa-se a palavra ["ludificación"](https://es.glosbe.com/es/es/ludificaci%C3%B3n) com o mesmo sentido, constando no dicionário [Sensagent](http://diccionario.sensagent.com/Gamificaci%C3%B3n/es-es/) como uma alternativa de "gamificación". Há inclusive algumas discussões quanto ao uso desse termo, com a adição de uma terceira alternativa, "jueguización", que me parece ser a menos usada: [1](https://www.snackson.com/gamificacion-gamification-ludificacion-como-me-llamo/), [2](http://terminologiayneologia.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/ludificacion-mejor-que-gamificacion.html), [3](http://www.gamerdic.es/termino/gamificacion).

Em catalão, há o termo "ludificació", constado no glossário Terminológico Catalão [TermCat](http://www.termcat.cat/ca/Cercaterm/Fitxa/ludificaci%C3%B3/Mjg5ODUwMw==/).

Em francês, há o termo ["ludification"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ludification), constado nos dicionários [Digital Learning Academy](https://digital-learning-academy.com/tag/ludification/), e no [Definitions Marketing](https://www.definitions-marketing.com/definition/ludification/), este último um glossário de termos relativos ao marketing.

Curiosamente, em latim existia o verbo ["ludificare"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ludifico), com o sentido de "debochar, tirar sarro, zoar", mas parece que esse termo se perdeu no português e reapareceu agora, com outro sentido, devido à necessidade de tradução. Esse verbo latino ainda se mantém no italiano ["ludificare"](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=ludificare), com o sentido de "ludibriar/iludir".