# Qual a origem e significado da palavra "gamificação"?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Li hoje em um post no pt.so sobre *gamificação* no contexto de software (ainda sem resposta).

Entretanto o que significa *gamificação* e qual a sua origem? (Pelo menos no contexto do pt-br)

P.S.: Pergunto também pois ao pesquisar sobre sua definição, não encontrei a mesma em nenhum dicionário, veja:

- [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- [Michaeli](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/)
- [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/pesquisa.php?q=gamifica%E7%E3o)

Sem nenhuma explicação em qualquer deles.

Comment: Gamificação é o aportuguesamento do termo inglês "gamification", que significa "o ato de transformar algo em jogo" ou "o ato de aplicar a mecânica dos jogos em algo". Já há uma duvida similar, basta clicar [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/h%C3%A1-uma-alternativa-culta-para-o-anglicismo-neologismo-gamificar/4616#4616).

Answer (score 4):

***Gamificação***, também conhecida por ***ludificação***, é a adição de jogos ou características típicas de jogos a outras atividades para as tornar mais interessantes e estimular a participação nelas. Por exemplo, este site está todinho gamificado, pois as pessoas recebem pontos e medalhas por contribuírem com respostas e perguntas que agradem aos restantes membros da comunidade.

Já tens esta [pergunta e respetiva resposta sobre alternativa à palavra *gamificar*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/h%C3%A1-uma-alternativa-culta-para-o-anglicismo-neologismo-gamificar/4616#4616), que dá mais informação sobre este tópico. De facto, *gamificação* e a alternativa *ludificação* não aparecem nos dicionários Aulete, Michaelis ou Dicio. Mas encontra-las na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o); este último sugere também como alternativa [*joguificação*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/JOGUIFICA%C3%87%C3%83O), mas uma [busca no Google](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&q=joguifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o&oq=joguifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2464400.2468269.0.2468949.12.12.0.0.0.0.109.997.10j2.12.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.519...0j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1.0.GGvVsgQfkYA) revela que essa palavra praticamente não é usada. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) tem também um artigo extenso sobre os assunto.

A palavra vem do inglês *gamification*, de *game* (‘jogo’), que segundo o [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gamify) apareceu apenas em 2010!

Answer (score 4):

Gamificação, do inglês *gamification* (de *game)*, é a promoção do engajamento do público em certo produto ou serviço por meio de maneiras alternativas.

As comunidades do StackExchange, o Portuguese Language é uma delas, [promovem a gamificação](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/). Os pontos, medalhas, privilégios e a interação social cativam o usuário a perguntar e responder mais.

Um aplicativo conhecido para aprendizado de idiomas, Duolingo, também [promove a ludificação através do sistema competitivo](http://www.gamification.co/2015/08/12/gamified-design-review-a-in-depth-analysis-of-duolingo/).

Esse conceito todo não se prende ao mundo virtual. [Empresas estão gamificando processos para engajar seus funcionários](https://www.clicksoftware.com/blog/top-25-best-examples-of-gamification-in-business/) a buscarem mais produtividade, conhecimento e etc.

A [primeira referência](http://www.nanodome.com/conundra.co.uk/) de "gamification" foi em 2002-2003 por Nick Pelling, embora tenha sido popularizado a partir de 2010, como mostra este gráfico com a frequência de buscas do **tópico**:

[image]
 <sub>Fonte: [Google Trends (Ludificação - tópico)](https://trends.google.com.br/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F0cm8xv9)</sub>

O [gráfico do termo "gamification"](https://trends.google.com.br/trends/explore?date=all&q=gamification) se assemelha ao gráfico do tópico Ludificação, o que mostra que os dois cresceram em conjunto.

A ascensão do termo aportuguesado é um pouco mais recente:

[image]

Comment: Interessante. O Merriam-Webster não apanhou essa ocorrência. Teria interesse também era o gráfico para "gamificação".

Comment: Creio que os teus dois gráficos não são comparáveis: mostras o **tópico** *ludificação*, que creio que inclui nomeadamente *ludificacion* em espanhol e coisas assim; e o **termo** *gamificação* que é só gamificação. Vê [aqui](https://trends.google.com.br/trends/explore?date=all&q=Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o,gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) os termos *gamificação* e *ludificação* juntos no mesmo gráfico.